# Cancelling a net.Listener via Context in Golang

Tags: go, tcp

I'm implementing a TCP server application that accepts incoming TCP connections in an infinite loop.

I'm trying to use Context throughout the application to allow shutting down, which is generally working great.

The one thing I'm struggling with is cancelling a net.Listener that is waiting on Accept().  I'm using a ListenConfig which, I believe, has the advantage of taking a Context when then creating a Listener.  However, cancelling this Context does not have the intended effect of aborting the Accept call.

Here's a small app that demonstrates the same problem:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    lc := net.ListenConfig{}

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2*time.Second)
        fmt.Println("cancelling context...")
        cancel()
    }()
    ln, err := lc.Listen(ctx, "tcp", ":9801")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error creating listener:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("listen returned without error")
        defer ln.Close()
    }
    conn, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("accept returned error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("accept returned without error")
        defer conn.Close()
    }
}
```

I expect that, if no clients connect, when the Context is cancelled 2 seconds after startup, the Accept() should abort.  However, it just sits there until you Ctrl-C out.

Is my expectation wrong?  If so, what is the point of the Context passed to ListenConfig.Listen()?

Is there another way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: The best I've been able to come up with is starting a routine that waits on ctx.Done() and then calls ln.Close(). It works but seems like it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you should be closing the listener when your timeout runs out. Then, when `Accept` returns an error, check that it's intentional (e.g. the timeout elapsed).

[This blog post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/graceful-shutdown-of-a-tcp-server-in-go/) shows how to do a safe shutdown of a TCP server without a context. The interesting part of the code is:

```
type Server struct {
    listener net.Listener
    quit     chan interface{}
    wg       sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewServer(addr string) *Server {
    s := &Server{
        quit: make(chan interface{}),
    }
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s.listener = l
    s.wg.Add(1)
    go s.serve()
    return s
}

func (s *Server) Stop() {
    close(s.quit)
    s.listener.Close()
    s.wg.Wait()
}

func (s *Server) serve() {
    defer s.wg.Done()

    for {
        conn, err := s.listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            select {
            case <-s.quit:
                return
            default:
                log.Println("accept error", err)
            }
        } else {
            s.wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                s.handleConection(conn)
                s.wg.Done()
            }()
        }
    }
}

func (s *Server) handleConection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    buf := make([]byte, 2048)
    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Println("read error", err)
            return
        }
        if n == 0 {
            return
        }
        log.Printf("received from %v: %s", conn.RemoteAddr(), string(buf[:n]))
    }
}
```

In your case you should call `Stop` when the context runs out.

---

If you look at the source code of `TCPConn.Accept`, you'll see it basically calls the underlying socket `accept`, and the context is not piped through there. But `Accept` is simple to cancel by closing the listener, so piping the context all the way isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Right on. This is pretty much exactly what I'm doing in my current workaround, so I'll just stick with that.

As a relative newbie to Go, it does seem like the Context support in the standard libraries is quite inconsistent, but that's a discussion for another day.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, odd. Even the documentation is odd in this regard. The net package documentation mentions how to pass a context to Listen but never what the effect of a canceled context is to Listen. Normally the documentation around the effects of a passed context are quite good. I also found it didn't affect the current accept or even subsequent ones. Listen plumbing takes the context down to the initial socket creation for the listener itself. Interestingly I think, the goroutine route of watching the context to close the listener is what the stdlib itself is doing to get listener creation to timeout.